# I can't input certain characters on the PHPStorm Terminal

Tags: keyboard, phpstorm

I'm currently using JetBrains' PHPStorm IDE and I'm having problems using the embedded terminal with a Portuguese Keyboard (correctly set up on Windows). I can't input certain characters like "[", "{" or "]", which I can only access using the "Alt Gr" key, despite characters common too all keyboard layouts working just fine.

Is there any way to fix this? I'm forced to use the windows console to perform certain tasks because of this problem, which makes the IDE terminal a bit useless to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue that is [fixed already](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152291).

You will have to wait till next update (v2016.1.1) will be publicly available -- it's expected to be somewhere in a week time (no precise date for the moment, unfortunately).

In meantime you can either use English keyboard layout ... or keep using external console app.